# Python Word Scramble/Jumble - how does this scramble a word?

Tags: python, random, while-loop, cpu-word, scramble

I have a python program here that unscrambles a word, but I'm not sure what is happening in a specific section.

In the section that is blockquoted and separated by headers below, I don't understand why the 'scrambling' of the word is put into a while loop - could it not work without the loop? Also, can someone explain everything happening inside of that while loop (while word:)?

```
import random
words = ('coffee', 'phone', 'chair', 'alarm')
word = random.choice(words)

correct = word
scramble = ""
```

---

> ```
> while word:
>     position = random.randrange(len(word))
>     scramble += word[position]
>     word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]
> ```

---

```
print("The scrambled word is: ", scramble)
answer = input("What's your guess?: ")

def unscramble(answer):
    while answer != correct and answer != "":
        print("Sorry, incorrect.")
        answer = input("Try again: ")
    if answer == correct:
        print("Good job, that is correct!")

unscramble(answer)
```

Comment: I suggest adding `print(word)` (twice), `print(position)`, `print(scramble)` inside your `while word` loop. A good way to figure out what's going on inside blocks of code is to litter them with print statements and then run the code.

Comment: Thanks, but where would I add these print statements into the code? Sorry, I'm very new to this.

Comment: For each line in the while loop, if you can't figure out what the relevant values of your variables are, print them.

Comment: It's ok if it involves some experimentation, or you add a print statement and then delete it or comment it out. It's worth practicing this process for figuring out what the code is doing.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot with the first two lines in the while loop. Though the bottom line in the loop doesn't give me a clear idea of what is happening when I print(word).

Comment: If you edit your question to show the print statements you're including and the console output, then if you have a question about why a certain variable has a certain value when it's printed, I can answer that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the while loop one line at a time.

```
while word:
```

This is just a shorthand for saying `while len(word) > 0`. It means that the loop will continue until `word` is empty.

```
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
```

This line uses the standard library `random.randrange` function to get a (pseudo)random number between 0 and `len(word) - 1` inclusive.

```
    scramble += word[position]
```

Here, the character at the random position in the word is being added to the scrambled word.

```
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]
```

Finally, this line deletes the randomly-chosen character from the original word using slicing. The expression `word[:position]` means "the substring of `word` up to (but not including) the index `position`". So if `position` is 3, then `word[:position]` would be the first three characters of word as a string. Similarly, `word[(position + 1):]` means "the substring of `word` starting at index `position + 1`".

The whole expression ends up being "`word` except for the character at index `position`", because you're concatenating the part of `word` up to `position` with the part of `word` starting at `position + 1`. Unfortunately, this is the most graceful way to delete a character from a string in Python.

To summarize: the while loop chooses a random character of the original word, adds it to the scrambled word, and deletes it from the original. It continues to do this until there are no characters left in the original.